# how to insert my_html into joomla article so that formatting is preserved

Tags: html, css, joomla, article

I have a large amount of html that I want to copy and paste into a joomla article.

Once I insert my_html into joomla, my_html inherits all of the wrapping css.

my_html was derived from a pdf --> html conversion (Open Office Writer), so much of it uses attributes instead of styles, especially table borders.

Ideally I would like to shield my_html's styles from the wrapping joomla environment, but I do not think that that is possible.

---

**EDIT** ... here's an example:

in my_html I have a table; one cell is set up to have a border, the rest should be borderless; but somewhere in the wrapper, upstream, there is a border = 1 which thus affects all cells.

Of course in this example I could fix this fairly easily, but there are lots and lots of other similar issues ... hence, it would be nice to shield my_html.

Comment: I think that the only simple solution would be to use an iframe, which doesn't let css styling pass through. This would take some doing to set up though. The only other solution would likely be to actually fix the css inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only if you use `CodeMirror` as your article editor. `TinyMCe` editor strips your CSS or any js you're using.

Comment: I use jce editor, and have it set Not to strip css and js. Please see my EDIT for an example ... thanks.

Comment: I insist on using CodeMirror just to make your edits and then change your editor back to JCE editor. I have used Joomla since v1 and I had similar problems with editors.